# Option Field In TCP Header

Tags: network, networking, network-theory

In the tcp field option There are several options that can be added for example like mss But how if i don't use the SACK option, what kind of acknolegdment will I use cummulative?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

ACK is always cumulative - you ACK all data before the SEQ indicated and expect the next data segment starting with SEQ.

Selective ACK is an option to acknowledge data *behind* a missing segment without acknowledging the missing data itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir